# PCI vs. PCIe wireless network card

Tags: wireless-networking, pci-express, pci

I currently have a PCI 802.11n wireless network card (TP-LINK TL-WN951N 300M). Would a PCIe network card improve 1. **download speed** and/or 2. **range** (i.e. the bars that windows shows when talking about wireless connectivity in the bottom right corner of the screen)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wireless N](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11n) maximum possible data rate is 600 Mbps. That's 75 MB/sec. [PCI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conventional_PCI) data rate is at least 133 MB/sec. So, PCI bus is most probably not your bottleneck.

Regarding the wireless range, chipset and antenna play a major role, not the connection/bus technology. So a better card with an external antenna connector, with a better antenna, will have a longer range. PCI or PCIe, it's not important.

First figure out where your bottleneck is, I suspect it's your Internet connection (from your router to the Internet), and not a wireless link from your computer to the router.

Comment: *> First figure out where your bottleneck is, I suspect it's your Internet connection*   Or from the ISP in regards to the total speed. As for range, that's probably being limited by the power of the card (check the settings; you may be running in reduced power and can configure it to use more), not to mention walls and such. In short, haimg is correct; the bus connector of the card plays pretty much *zero* role for a network card (at least a wireless one; a wired one connected to a gigabit intranet may matter).

Comment: while pci is capable of being 64 bit and double speed (66) MHz, these varieties are very rarely seen outside of servers.